# Server version disclosed in case of HTTP 500 coming because of blocked VERB hit

Tags: c#, security, iis, web-config

I have put custom error page and put Verb blocking, allowing only GET and POST.
But when I am trying other method (DELETE, OPTION, TRACE), it is not redirecting to custom error page, also it is **disclosing Server Version**. Server version is not disclosed in HTTP 200.

**Error Page Handling -:**

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="Redirect" >
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="SSPERR.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="500"  path="SSPERR.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

**Rules**

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto"  defaultResponseMode="Redirect" >
          <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="SSPERR.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
          <error statusCode="500"  path="SSPERR.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
        </httpErrors>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
              <clear/>
              <add verb="GET" allowed="true"/>
              <add verb="POST" allowed="true"/>
            </verbs>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <rewrite>
          <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
            <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
              <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+"/>
              <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
            </rule>
          </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

**Global.asax file -:**

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs 
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found problem :

You **forgot remove error 404 but add again and duplicated**. For this reason application throws exception in exception and Headers could not remove correctly.
Now You can see everythings ok. And I offer use plain html file for error pages. So error.html would be better.

```cs
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto"  defaultResponseMode="File" >
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/error.html" responseMode="File"/>
      <error statusCode="500"  path="~/error.html" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: This also is added in web.config. still server version is displayed.

Comment: I fixed it. please check it again now.

Comment: Server version is now not getting disclosed. But now it is throwing 404 error, but not redirecting to error page.

Comment: It is  redirecting after setting responseMode = "Redirect"


<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto"  defaultResponseMode="Redirect" >
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="SSPERR.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="500"  path="SSPERR.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>